# a misunderstanding about lists and multiple iterations

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, tuples

I am in high school taking programming classes in Python and I came across something weird. I think this is just my mistake but i don't know why when typing :

```py
L = []
x = []
for i in range(4):  
    x.append(0)
    L.append(x)
print (L)
```

The output shows this:

> [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

instead of this:

> [[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

I became curious after searching ways to make grids, my project is a crude battleship game i have to make with a grid

I think it would be logical the first list appended would only have one object in it since it was iterating for the first time, therefore the length of "x" would be equal to 1 and not 4.

Comment: You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it would be logical the first list appended would only have one object in it since it was iterating for the first time, therefore the length of "x" would be equal to 1 and not 4.

The first list appended has only one `0` in it. But it is the same list you call `.append(0)` on in the next iteration of you loop.

### What does your code currently do?

- You create two lists, `x` and `y`.
- Then you loop 4 times and

  - append a zero to the list in `x`
  - append the list `x` to the list `L`

As result you have the very same list `x` with four zeros four times in the list `L`

### What you really want your code to do

- You create two lists, `x` and `y`.
- Then you loop 4 times and

  - append a zero to the list in `x`
  - append **a copy** of the list `x` to the list `L`

### How your code should look like

There are several ways to copy a list in Python:

- With [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings):

  ```py
  >>> x = [1,2,3]
  >>> y = x[:]
  >>> x.append(4)
  >>> y
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```
- With the [`copy` method of any mutable sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) (Python3 only):

  ```py
  >>> x = [1,2,3]
  >>> y = x.copy()
  >>> x.append(4)
  >>> y
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```
- With the `list()` constructor:

  ```py
  >>> x = [1,2,3]
  >>> y = list(x)
  >>> x.append(4)
  >>> y
  [1, 2, 3]
  ```

So your code could look like:

```py
x = []
L = []

for _ in range(4):
    x.append(0)
    L.append(x[:])

print(L)
```

Output:

> [[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: how thank you for the detailed response! so are you saying when i append 0 for the second time to "a", the "a" list that was already appended during the first iteration to "L" also changes? Because that way it would make sense

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. After the loop you only have two lists. One with four zeros and one that contains the other list for four times